# SpringJUnit4ClassRunner does not load the test properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am trying to boot up a spring boot test, with a mapstruct implementation provided.
I am using the configuration below, but the application.properties file in the resources directory is not being read into the test.

How do I get the test below to read the default properties file, the file exist in `test/resources` and other spring boot tests are able to load it.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringBootExampleConfig.class)
public class SpringBootExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private IMapper mapper;


    @Test
    public void test() {
    }

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = SpringBootExampleTest.class)
    public static class SpringTestConfig {
    }

}
```

Comment: Why should it? You only construct a config with some detection, this isn't bootstrapping Spring boot. Remove the config, ditch `@ContextConfiguration` and add `@SpringBootTest` if you want a fully started context.

Comment: I just want to add the properties.